Transparent offcanvas fixed navbar change color on scroll
I've created a navbar with a transparent background. With JS I'm trying to change the navigation bar to a solid color when anyone scrolls down.
When you scroll the box-shadow at the bottom of the navbar changes rather than the color
Navigation bar expected to change colors when you scroll:
.navbar-scrolled{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

<script>
  const navEl = document.querySelector('.navbar');

  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if (window.scrollY >= 56) {
      navEl.classList.add('navbar-scrolled');
    }
    else if (window.scrollY < 56) {
      navEl.classList.remove('navbar-scrolled');
    }
  });
</script>


What first comes to my mind, you are not using css codes in <style>.
Second using bootstrap the background and color are fixed with important, so you should do it too. e.g.
background-color: #fff important;

Wish you luck ;)
